# Login fails on real device("iphone") but works on ipad ans simulators

Tags: ios, iphone

I am not sure if somebody has faced this type of issue , if somebody has any clue please let me know.

I have build an ios app which of which one of the functionality is **authentication using email and password** .Now registration , login everything works fine on simulators , when i checked on real device it works on ipad but on iphone the authentication never works , it always fails even though user is providing the correct username and password.

What can be the cause behind it ? I gone through few links and tested archive with debug and release both mode nothing works.

Comment: Not enough information.  Do some debugging and you'll find where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you do auth by send request to server??
if so, if you don't know why it is always failed to auth on device(iphone), you can capture a request package by using charles. it is easy to use.

charles:
http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: I used charles to check that yes I am sending auth request to server with email and password , there is no problem in request  as its works fine in ipad and I checked it with charles as well..I am very new to ios app is there any better way to debug where it goes wrong in real device

Comment: you mean that two request on two device is the same?, include the request parameters and request url? And the result is different? then is really impossible, if you can find a person to debug it on the server side, it would be great help. i always to debug in this way, and it really can help you find some tiny error. of course, are you sure that server didn't do some special operations for different platform?

Comment: yes both of them are using the same request to server for authentication including the url and parameters absolutely same but result is for some reason on real iphone device it doesn't work but all seems fine on simulators and on ipad(real device). I am trying hard to find out whats the issue , its strange but thats how its behaving